# How can I view blue "replace" suggestions in Preview?

Tags: preview

In Preview, how can I see the suggested replacements noted by blue strikethroughs? Do I need adobe acrobat to view these?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem to work. I used Adobe Reader DC, it's free.